# Retrieving shared prefrences values in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, if-statement

Can anyone tell where i am wrong because its just a simple process but how its not retrieving the values i cant understand and do conditional check over the string variable...

Activity A:-

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        EditText e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        EditText e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);

        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("text", e.getText().toString());
        SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs1", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = myPrefs1.edit();
        editor1.putString("text1", e1.getText().toString());

    SharedPreferences myPrefs2 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs2", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = myPrefs.edit();
        editor2.putString("text2", e2.getText().toString());

SharedPreferences myPrefs3 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs3", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor3 = myPrefs3.edit();
        editor3.putString("text3", e3.getText().toString());

SharedPreferences myPrefs4 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs4", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = myPrefs4.edit();
        editor4.putString("text4", e4.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences myPrefs5 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs5", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = myPrefs5.edit();
        editor5.putString("text5", e5.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences myPrefs6 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs6", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = myPrefs6.edit();
        editor6.putString("text6", e6.getText().toString());
```

Activity B:-In this activity i am accessing the values and doing the conditional check but only else condition is getting executed on both cases

```
public class CheckActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText = myPrefs.getString("text", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText1 = myPrefs1.getString("text1", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs2 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs2",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText2 =myPrefs2.getString("text2", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs3 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs3",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText3 =myPrefs3.getString("text3", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs4 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs4",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText4 = myPrefs4.getString("text4", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs5 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs5",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
        String restoredText5 = myPrefs5.getString("text5", "");
        SharedPreferences myPrefs6 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs6",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText6 = myPrefs6.getString("text6", "");
    Intent i1 = new Intent();
    if((restoredText.length()>1)&&(restoredText1.length()>1)&&(restoredText2.length()>1)&&(restoredText3.length()>1)&&(restoredText4.length()>1)&&(restoredText5.length()>1)&&(restoredText6.length()>1))
        {
             i1.setClass(this,ShpoonkleActivity.class);
        }
        //if((restoredText.length()==0)||(restoredText1.length()==0)||(restoredText2.length()==0)||(restoredText3.length()==0)||(restoredText4.length()==0)||(restoredText5.length()==0)||(restoredText6.length()==0))
    else    
    {
            i1.setClass(this,Test.class);
    }
        startActivity(i1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually saving edittext's text was creating ambiguity and hence was not executing well so i did this as shown below:-

Activity B:-

```
protected void onPause() {
        EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText ed3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText ed4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        EditText ed5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        EditText ed6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);

        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString("text", ed.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text1", ed1.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text2", ed2.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text3", ed3.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text4", ed4.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text5", ed5.getText().toString());
        editor.putString("text6", ed6.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Activity A:-

```
public class CheckActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        String restoredText = myPrefs.getString("text", "");
        String restoredText1 = myPrefs.getString("text1", "");
        String restoredText2 =myPrefs.getString("text2", "");
        String restoredText3 =myPrefs.getString("text3", "");
        String restoredText4 = myPrefs.getString("text4", "");
        String restoredText5 = myPrefs.getString("text5", "");
        String restoredText6 = myPrefs.getString("text6", "");
    Intent i1 = new Intent();
    if((restoredText.length()>0)&&(restoredText1.length()>0)&&(restoredText2.length()>0)&&(restoredText3.length()>0)&&(restoredText4.length()>0)&&(restoredText5.length()>0)&&(restoredText6.length()>0))
        {
             i1.setClass(this,ShpoonkleActivity.class);
        }
        //if((restoredText.length()==0)||(restoredText1.length()==0)||(restoredText2.length()==0)||(restoredText3.length()==0)||(restoredText4.length()==0)||(restoredText5.length()==0)||(restoredText6.length()==0))
    else    
    {
            i1.setClass(this,Test.class);
    }
        startActivity(i1);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And it works awesome ...thnx..

Answer (score 4):

you should commit your data with `editor.commit();`

**NB: in your case , there is no need to use a lot of instances of `SharedPreferences` , you need just one instance, and then put all your Strings into it , and commit**

Comment: thnx for that i rectified that mistake than also still my else condition is getting executed..

Comment: +1 (for "lot of instances") i think that he dont need SharedPreferences at all, but he don't know how to use extras in intents :) ...

Comment: @Selvin : i dont know if he needs to be able to get those strings after restarting app , or just to pass it to another activity , in this case as you said , he just need to use Extras of the intent :)

Comment: @Gaurav : i think the issue is that you are using the Mode readable , try to modify it with : 0  , in the both of your activities and try. and make sure that in your editText you entered strings which have a length of 2 characters or more ( or just test if str.length()>0 )

Comment: i should clear one thing @selvin that the activity where i am doing the conditional check is my main activity otherwise i would have used getIntent.getExtras().Actually my application has a very complex structure in which firstly my activity is checking is do my form edittext has value if yes then it would start another acivity and if dnt means shared pref string is empty then open that form activity...thanx..

Comment: you can do check procedure in other class (even in static method) (not extending Activity) it could check and fx return null or Bundle `static Bundle check(Context ctxForFxShowingToastOrDialogOr, OrInterface forCallback, String text1, String text2, ...){/*do check here*/}` so you could reuse this class/method in other activities ... if its a information about login you could use "Account/Sync API" on android above 2.2 ...

Answer (score 2):

you should use

```
editor.commit();
```

for your changes to be preserved. and also, you need not use different files to store various strings, you can store all the strings in the same shared preferences file.

Comment: thnx for that i rectified that mistake than also still my else condition is getting executed..

Comment: are you sure, you provided, a valid input to every editText, i.e a minimum of 2 chars in every editText? , i guess, you should check if string length is greater than 0, not 1, but i may be wrong too.